# laravel 5.3 installation error in windows 10

Tags: laravel

when installing laravel, there's an error

```
Failed to decode response: zlib_decode(): data error
Retrying with degraded mode, check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#degraded-mode for more info
```

what cause this error

Comment: Can you post a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Exemple](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Well according to the link that you posted:

-Disable HTTP-scanner if you use ESET antivirus

-Disable your ipv6 connection